# SQL: how to convert timestamp to datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert "2022-04-29T07:20:32.727Z" to "2022-04-29 07:20:32".
I am quite new to SQL and haven't found the solution.

Comment: conversion table for sql here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/ may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cast()

```
select cast('2022-04-29T07:20:32.727Z' as datetime)
```

| Output |
| --- |
| 2022-04-29 07:20:32.727 |

Comment: When doing this in PostgreSQL: `ERROR:  type "datetime" does not exist`

Comment: And if this is SQL Server, then the value the OP will get is nonsense; `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym for `rowversion` and has *nothing* to do with date and time.